# Correct use of foreach loop within foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I have the following data in my database:

```
initial   |    word
---------------------------
   E      |    Example1
   E      |    Example2
   N      |    Nextexample1
```

**The desired output:**

```
E
Example1
Example2

N
Nextexample1
```

So for each initial, it should display that initial and all the words starting with that initial. Important for me: each word should be displayed in a separate div so no `GROUP_CONCAT(`word`SEPARATOR ', ')` suggestions please.

**Output at this moment:**

```
E
Example1

E
Example2

N
Nextexample1
```

**My code at this moment:**

```
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=...');           
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT initial, word FROM `exampletable` ORDER by initial ASC";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmtrecords = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {

    foreach($stmtrecords as $result)
    {
?>

<div>
    <?php echo $result['initial'];?>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <?php echo $result['word'];?>
</div>
<br><br>
```

**The question:**

Obviously I need an extra loop to solve this problem but I don't know how to do that exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `group_concat` as

```
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=...');           
    $sql = "SELECT initial, group_concat(word) as word FROM `exampletable` group by initial ORDER by initial ASC";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmtrecords = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {

    foreach($stmtrecords as $result)
    {
       $words = $result['words'];
       $words_array = array();
       if(strlen($words) > 1) {
         $words_array = explode(',',$words);
       }
?>

<div>
    <?php echo $result['initial'];?>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <?php
     if (count($words_array) > 0 ){
       foreach($words_array as $val){
         echo $val.'<br />';
       }
     }
    ?>
    <?php echo $result['word'];?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need an extra loop, you just need a little extra logic in your loop. Since the query sorts the data by `initial`, you just need to check when `$result['initial']` changes in the loop and only output the header at that time.

```
$initial = null;

foreach ($stmtrecords as $result) {
    if ($result['initial'] !== $initial) {
        $initial = $result['initial'];
        // output header div
    }
    // output word
}
```

Just a word of caution: In your code above you are embedding data from the database directly into HTML. That data should be escaped before inserting in HTML. See [phptherightway.com](http://phptherightway.com) and the [Zend Escaper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.escaper.introduction.html) for more information on how to properly escape data.